# What's the simplest way to convert array keys with parenthesis to key -> subkey in php?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have this type of array coming back:

```
Array
(
    [data(0)] => somevalue
    [data(1)] => somevalue
    [data(2)] => somevalue
)
```

And I need converted to this:

```
Array (
    [data] => Array (somevalue
        [0] => somevalue
        [1] => somevalue
        [2] => somevalue
    )
)
```

Keep in mind there can be other keys, so simply running a for loop on the count and feeding each value in is not an option.

I thought I would really simplify things by posting the simple example above, but I guess that didn't tell enough of the story.

The data is a string back from PayPal. PayPal has a function called deformatNVP() which does the initial job of putting this in to an array, however it's not an array that PHP can handle. It can look like this:

```
Array(
    [responseEnvelope.ack] => somevalue
    [responseEnvelope.timestamp] => somevalue
    [responseEnvelope.build] => somevalue
    [responseEnvelope.correlationId] => somevalue
)
```

It can also have something like:

```
Array(
    [personalData(0)] => somevalue
    [personalData(1)] => somevalue
    [personalData(2)] => somevalue
)
```

That's completely ugly, so the first step below fixes the dotted arrays, but I am left with these keys with parenthesis to deal with.

```
$data = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

    $subkey = "";
    $_keys = explode('.', $key);

    if(count($_keys) > 1){
        $key = $_keys[0];
        $subkey = $_keys[1];
    }

    if(preg_match("/([0-9]+)/", $key, $matches)){
        $key = preg_replace("/\([0-9]+\)/", "", $key);
        $data[$key][$matches[0]][$subkey] = $value;
    }
    elseif($subkey)
        $data[$key][$subkey] = $value;
    else
        $data[$key] = $value;

}
return $data;
```

Comment: id be interested to know how you got this type of array keys...

Comment: Foreach loop? Regex match index? Capture integer? Store integer/value pair in new array with `data` index? Unset the old name/value pair?

Comment: it's actually in some responses from PayPal. They also return dotted keys (key.subkey=value) in the string you receive back in their name/value pair responses.

Comment: its not very clear what array you have and how you want the result array to be, can you post the full array given by paypal and also the full array of how you want the result array to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Sometimes there are keys that are dotted like: key.subkey

If something `.` can appear, sometimes other things can appear too. This specification should be clear enough before developing any algorithm to parse it.

So far It can be done by looping over each element and splitting information using [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split) function. Following code put the resultant array in `$result` variable.

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    list($text, $subkey) = preg_split('/\W+/', "$key:END", 3, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    if($subkey=='END'){
    $result[$text] = $value; continue;
    }else{
    $result[$text][$subkey] = $value;
    }
}
```

See http://ideone.com/CJHHZ

Remember it just splits the string with non word characters (`\W`). `\W` matches any characters other than `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` and `_`.

Comment: There will be an issue when the indices do not follow that pattern, such as, `key.subkey` index.

Comment: @Josh I have updated it. But I think you already know how to do it :)

Comment: I've already handled the key.subkey. Take a look at my edit above.

Comment: @Leigh in which array should I add it?

Comment: @Tomas in second edit (prior to current) I have changed it so it supports any non-word character as a delimiter. Also added some comments.

Comment: Looks good to me, it also is far less code than what I had going there.

Comment: Actually there's an error for any key that does not need splitting. For instance, 'foo' => 'bar' will result in [foo] => Array( [] => bar ) which is not right.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8320/discussion-between-shiplu-and-tomas)